# Using ModalEditor from highcharts-editor in Angular5

Tags: angular, highcharts, highcharts-editor

I am trying to use highcharts-editor in Angular5 but I am not able to get any of the objects/methods. (trying to use ModalEditor)

```
import * as higheditor from "highcharts-editor";
import { highed } from "highcharts-editor";
```

I have tried above, it gives an object but there is nothing in the object that looks useful. I couldn't find any documentation that can be useful for Angular implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Right now there is no way to implement it inside Angular Application unless if you are coming up with a bridge between Angular and Highcharts editor.

You can find from the **[`reference.`](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-editor/issues/119)** opened by me which is still in open.

Comment: I tried to add the javascript reference to index and it allows me to load up the modal editor but then it complains about missing highcharts.js. Half of my implementation is using angular2-highcharts package..hence it is complaining about missing highcharts.js. When I add highcharts.js to index, it gives error #16 and as per FAQ #16 means I am loading highcharts twice in same window